# Segmentation Fault trying to create linked list

Tags: c

I am currently studying C for the first time and for an assignment I need to create a linked lists. I've had no problems simple ones in the past however the functional abstraction and pointer passing seems to be confusing me as I can't get this one going. I keep receiving a segmentation fault when running the program. Basically I am reading data from 2 separate files then populating the lists. From there I make other to the data but at this stage it is irrelevant as I can't even load the data in from the files. The lists are controlled using the tm struct which is passed (&tm) from the main to the various functions.

I've been using Valgrind and gdb to try and diagnose but being new to debugging makes it difficult. After two days of trial and error I feel like there is something vital I am missing. Here is my code and error messages:

```
/* global type definitions */
typedef struct tm * tm_type_ptr;
typedef struct stock_list * stock_list_ptr;
typedef struct coin * coin_list_ptr;
typedef struct tm {
   coin_list_ptr coins;
   stock_list_ptr stock;
} tm_type;

/*coin structs*/
enum coin_types {
   FIVE_CENTS=5,
   TEN_CENTS=10,
   TWENTY_CENTS=20,
   FIFTY_CENTS=50,
   ONE_DOLLAR=100,
TWO_DOLLARS=200
};

struct coin {
   enum coin_types denomination;
   unsigned count;
};

/* stock structs*/
struct stock_data 
{
   char ticket_name[TICKET_NAME_LEN+1];
   char ticket_type;
   char ticket_zone[TICKET_ZONE_LEN+1];
   unsigned int ticket_price;
   unsigned int stock_level;
};

typedef struct stock_node 
{
   struct stock_data * data;
   struct stock_node * next_node;
} stock_node;

struct stock_list
{
   stock_node * head_stock;
   unsigned int num_stock_items;
};
```

Then to populate the structs I am using the following functions:

```
BOOLEAN system_init(tm_type * tm)
{

  tm->coins=malloc(sizeof(struct coin) * NUM_COINS);
  tm->stock=malloc(sizeof(struct stock_list));
  tm->stock->head_stock = malloc(sizeof(stock_node));
  tm->stock->head_stock->data = malloc(sizeof (struct stock_data));
  tm->coins->count = 0;
  tm->stock->num_stock_items =0;
  if (tm == NULL)
  {
     return FALSE;
  }
  else
  {
     return TRUE;
  } 
}

BOOLEAN load_data(tm_type * tm, char * stockfile, char * coinsfile)
{
  FILE *stock_fp = fopen(stockfile, "r");
  FILE *coins_fp = fopen(coinsfile, "r");
  char *input= NULL, *token = NULL;
  unsigned coin_type, amount;
  /*stock variables*/
  unsigned stock_count=0;
  unsigned int ticket_price, stock_level;

  char *ticket_name = NULL, ticket_type, *ticket_zone= NULL;
     while(fgets(input, buffer_size, coins_fp) != NULL)
     {
        token= strtok(input, ",");
        coin_type = strtol(token, NULL, 10);
        if(token != NULL)
        {
           token= strtok(NULL, ",");
           amount = strtol(token, NULL, 10);
        }

        if(!populate_coin_array(tm, coin_type, amount))
        {
           printf("OMG YOU SUCK!\n");
        } 
     }   
  } 
  /*display_coin_array(tm); */   
 }
 fclose(coins_fp);
 free(input);
 /*read stock file and populate stock structure */
 if(fseek(stock_fp ,0, SEEK_END) == 0)
 {
  long buffer_size = ftell(stock_fp);
  if(buffer_size == -1)
  {
     printf("Error! Exiting!\n");
     return FALSE;
  }
  input = malloc(sizeof(char) * (buffer_size+1));  /*allocate buffer size plus one for      `     '\0'*/

  if(fseek(stock_fp,0,SEEK_SET) == 0)
  {
     while(fgets(input, buffer_size, stock_fp) != NULL)
     {
        ticket_name = strtok(input, ",");
        ticket_type = *(strtok(NULL, ","));
        ticket_zone = strtok(NULL, ",");
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        ticket_price = strtol(token, NULL, 10);
        token = strtok(NULL,",");
        stock_level = strtol(token, NULL, 10);
        stock_count++;
        if(!populate_stock_list(tm, ticket_name, ticket_type, ticket_zone, 
        ticket_price, stock_level, stock_count))
        {
           printf("ERROR!!!\n");
        } 

     }    

  } 
  display_stock_list(tm, stock_count);  
}
fclose(stock_fp);
free(input);
return TRUE;
}

BOOLEAN populate_coin_array(tm_type *tm, unsigned coin_type, unsigned amount)
{
  struct coin single_coin;
  struct coin *coin_array;
  coin_array = malloc(sizeof(struct coin) * NUM_COINS);
  single_coin = *(tm->coins);
  single_coin.denomination = coin_type;
  single_coin.count = amount;
  *coin_array = single_coin;
  tm->coins = coin_array;
  return TRUE;
}

BOOLEAN populate_stock_list(tm_type *tm, char  *ticket_name, char ticket_type,
char *ticket_zone, unsigned int ticket_price, unsigned int stock_level, 
unsigned int stock_count)
{
   tm_type temp_list;
   struct stock_node *new_node;
   temp_list = *tm;
   new_node = malloc(sizeof(stock_node*));
   if(new_node != NULL)
   {
      strcpy(new_node->data->ticket_name, ticket_name);
      new_node->data->ticket_type = ticket_type;
      strcpy(new_node->data->ticket_zone , ticket_zone);
      new_node->data->ticket_price = ticket_price;
      new_node->data->stock_level = stock_level;
      new_node->next_node = temp_list.stock->head_stock;
      temp_list.stock->head_stock = new_node;
      temp_list.stock->num_stock_items = stock_count;
   }
   return TRUE;
 }
```

I am sorry for the massive pile of messy code, I have taken it from a number of .c and .h files. I've tried to trim down as much as possible to make it easier to troubleshoot.

Valgrind is giving me this:

```
==16716== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==16716==    at 0x4C2BFFC: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64- 
linux.so)
==16716==    by 0x400D37: populate_stock_list (tm_stock.c:37)
==16716==    by 0x40128F: load_data (tm_utility.c:129)
==16716==    by 0x40098F: main (tm.c:57)
==16716== 
==16716== Invalid write of size 1
==16716==    at 0x4C2BFFC: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-
linux.so)
==16716==    by 0x400D37: populate_stock_list (tm_stock.c:37)
==16716==    by 0x40128F: load_data (tm_utility.c:129)
==16716==    by 0x40098F: main (tm.c:57)
==16716==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==16716== 
==16716== 
==16716== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==16716==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==16716==    at 0x4C2BFFC: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-
linux.so)
==16716==    by 0x400D37: populate_stock_list (tm_stock.c:37)
==16716==    by 0x40128F: load_data (tm_utility.c:129)
==16716==    by 0x40098F: main (tm.c:57)
```

Can help point me in the right direction? I don't expect anyone to give me the answer, I'd just like to know why this is happening.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate for `new_node->data` which is `struct stock_data *` before using it.
Also, in `malloc()` pass size of structure you allocating for not size of its pointer.

Update would be

```
//--------------------------------v no * here
new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
if(new_node != NULL)
{
    new_node->data = malloc(sizeof(*(new_node->data)));
    ...
    //your code
```

Comment: Thanks Rohan, that was it! I was scratching my head trying to think where I wasn't allocating memory. I understood where Valgrind was sending me too, I just thought I wasn't allocating memory earlier. Thank you again man, I really appreciate it!

Comment: I believe the "sizeof pointer" is a mis-understanding ... It should be `new_node = malloc(sizeof *new_node);`, that removes the need to type out the name of a type, and "locks" the allocated size to the size of an actual expression which can be easily verified to be the proper one, i.e. the pointer receiving `malloc()`'s return value.